# Get text from div using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm using Selenium and Python to extract information from a page.

Here is the *div* I want to extract from:

```html
<div class="_2v66">5</div>
```

I want to extract the value "5".

Here is the Python I have written:

```python
element = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_2v66').getText

print('Views:')
print(element)
```

When I run this script, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 95, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getText'
[Finished in 15.478s]
```

Solution:

Although I originally thought the *div* class was unique, after a closer inspection of the page I realized that it is not a unique *div* and therefore the solution was as follows:

```
browser.get(('https://www.facebook.com/example_page_1/insights/?section=navVideos'))

browser.implicitly_wait(60)

# find_elements_by_class_name - Returns the div in which the metrics are found
elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_2v66')

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

The `browser.implicitly_wait` was crucial to allow the page to load. The errors I was receiving with regards to the object no existing were because of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use just `.text`

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_2v66').text
```

If there are multiple elements, you'll have to loop through them.

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_2v66')
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: It's still giving me  " File "<string>", line 94, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' "

Comment: Check the two statements, if you use `find_elements` it returns a list whereas `find_element` will return the single element

Comment: It is still giving me an error saying "unable to locate element"

Answer (score 3):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to extract the text **5**, instead of using `find_elements*` you need to use **`find_element`** and you can use the following solution:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_2v66').text
print(element)
```

**Note A**: The Selenium-Python client doesn't have any method `getText`, but instead `text`.

**Note B**: You have to ensure that this particular `<div>` tag can be uniquely identified through the *class* attribute **_2v66**.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of selenium ([docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)):

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'css-449o1m')
print(element.text)
```